# F# and generic types

Tags: .net, f#

Its possible to create this in f#?

```
public TTarget Map<TTarget>(string SQL) where TTarget : new()
{
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do - that's not using anonymous types at all; it's a generic method.

Comment: Yes its true its a generic , i confused. I trying convert this to F#

Comment: So what did your research into generic methods in F# bring up? See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Look, i searched about this and not founded anything. I tried but can't founded answers. If i founded it. i don't questioned.

Comment: My question is how to i can make this part in f# "where TTarget : new()"

Comment: Evidence of that research would have been useful. Searching for F# generics finds plenty of links. (If you searched for anonymous types, that wouldn't have helped - which is why it's so important to make sure you use terminology carefully.)

Comment: I searched for generics but when writed this i confused and put anonymous, i know the difference. My problem is i not founded syntax for this part "new: unit -> 'T"

Comment: For future reference, the term you're looking for is a "generic type constraint".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx for the list of possible constraints in F# and some examples of how to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let map<'T when 'T: (new: unit -> 'T)> (sql: string) =
    new 'T()
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the constraint is unnecessary. This works just as well.

```ml
let map (sql: string) = new 'T()
```